# Coupling a chi-square to a normal random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Let $Z\sim \chi^2(k)$ be a random variable sampled from the [Chi-Squared distribution with $k$ degrees of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution).

*Vague question:* Conditional on the value of $Z$, how can I reconstruct a sequence of i.i.d. standard Gaussians $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^k$ such that $Z=\sum_i X_i^2$?

*Precise question:* Let $U$ be a uniform $[0,1]$ random variable. Is there a sequence of deterministic functions $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^k$ such that $\{f_i(Z,U)\}_{i=1}^k$ are a sequence of i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ random variables satisfying $\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(Z,U)^2=Z$ a.s.?

Comment: Draw $V$ uniformly randomly on the unit sphere of $\mathbb R^k$, independently of $Z$, and set $X_i=V_i\sqrt{Z}$ for every $i$. Then $(X_i)$ is i.i.d. standard normal and, obviously, $X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2=Z$. To write $V$ as a function of some random variable $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$, use the method you like most.

Comment: Is there a simple way to see that the $X_i$ are iid Gaussian?

Comment: Sure: go in the other direction, that is, start from $X=(X_i)$ i.i.d. standard normal and show that $R^2=X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2$ and $X/R$ are independent with $X/R$ uniform on the unit sphere.

Comment: How do you prove uniqueness of the distribution?

Comment: Which uniqueness?

Comment: If I understand your argument correctly, you are showing that the $X_i$ may be sampled from a Gaussian distribution. But how do you show that it is the *unique* distribution with these properties? I.e., why do the conditions you have given in your previous comment characterize the distribution?

Comment: Sorry but I fail to see your point. The procedure I indicated in my first comment does yield the correct distribution. To prove that it does, one can proceed as indicated in my second comment. What else is there to say?